# Is this a bug of jQuery Callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I am currently looking into source code of jQuery 1.8.1, and found that there maybe something wrong with jQuery:

First, disable a callback using `disable()`, then call `empty()`, then add a function using `add()`, finally call `fire()`, as the API explains about the `disable()` :

> Disable a callback list from doing anything more

The last call to `fire()` should output nothing, but actually, it output '2' as if the `disable()` is not called;

```
var a = $.Callbacks();
a.add(function(){console.log('1');});
a.disable();
a.disabled();  //true
a.empty();
a.add(function(){console.log('2');});
a.fire();   //2
```

So is this a jQuery bug?

Comment: If it is a bug, it's a bug in a 2 year old version of JQuery.

Comment: Yeah, but i am reading source code of jQuery based on that version.

Comment: Works the same in all jQuery versions I tested (including 2.1).

Comment: Why do you think its a bug? You have called the `empty` method which _Remove all of the callbacks from a list_. And then you again added a anonymous function so it should gets fire.

Comment: @Jon em, you are right.

Comment: @RahilWazir but i call `disable()` first. And if i call `fire()` before calling `disable()`, the last call to `fire()` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bug in jQuery, at least not inside `disable`. Calling `disable` does indeed make the callbacks object inert for all practical purposes.

Your code sample however also calls `empty`, which re-initializes the callbacks object and in doing so returns it in a usable state. *That* might be a bug, since `empty` is not documented to do this.

Removing the call to `empty` obviously results in the expected behavior.

Comment: Or `empty` before `disable` will give you the expected behavior.

Comment: Why not add flags to control Callback object's state? There are `fired`, `firing`, why not adding a `disabled` and `locked`?

Comment: @YuC: I don't know. I 've been reading the jQuery source and it seems to me that the developers did not intend for `empty` to reset the callbacks object like that, which would make this a bug.

Comment: @YuC: Convinced that this is a bug in `.empty()`, I filed [an issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13517) with jQuery and added [a PR on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/1643). Hopefully this will get fixed soon.

Comment: @Jon Nice work, thanks. I saw the PR you added on Github, quite simple, i am wondering why haven't i do that.